# i want to multiply 3 input fields and out into fourth field below is my code

Tags: jquery

i want to multiply those three fields
i have used html and jquery
i will be thankful for your assistance

here is my html code

```
<input type="text" id="the_input_id"> 
<input type="text" id="the_input_id1"> 
<input type="text" id="the_input_id2"> 
<input type="text" id="total">
```

this is my jquery

```
<script >
$(function() {    
$('#the_input_id, #the_input_id1').keyup(function(){
   updateTotal(); 
});    
var updateTotal = function () {
  var input1 = parseInt($('#the_input_id').val());
  var input2 = parseInt($('#the_input_id1').val());
  if (isNaN(input1) || isNaN(input2)) {
      if(!input2){
          $('#total').val($('#the_input_id').val());
      }
       if(!input1){
            $('#total').val($('#the_input_id1').val());
      }
      } else {          
        $('#total').val(input1 * input2);      }
};
 var output_total = $('#total');    
var total = input1 * input2;    
output_total.val(total);    
});    
 </script>
```

Comment: What problems are your facing? since you have been able to make it with 2 inputs, making it into 3 should not be that hard

Answer (score 1):

You can use key up listener with loop like this.

```js
$('input[id*="the_input"]').keyup(function () {
    var result = 1;
    var x=0;
    $('input[id*="the_input"]').each(function () {
        if (this.value != '') {
            result *= this.value ;
            x++;
        }
    });
    $('#total').val((x == 0) ?0:result);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="the_input_id"> 
<input type="text" id="the_input_id1"> 
<input type="text" id="the_input_id2"> 
<input type="text" id="total">
```

Comment: This is way better than an if-else conditional :)

Answer (score 0):

You were closing your function too early - moving the curly bracket allows the calculation to proceeed. I also simplified your logic a bit.

```js
$(function() {    
  $('input').keyup(function(){
    updateTotal(); 
  });   
  
var updateTotal = function () {
  var input1 = parseInt($('#the_input_id1').val()) || null;
  var input2 = parseInt($('#the_input_id2').val()) || null;
  var input3 = parseInt($('#the_input_id3').val()) || null;
  var total = input1 * input2 * input3;   
   
  if (input1 && input2 && input3) {        
      $('#total').val(total);  
    }
  } // bracket moved to here allows the update of the output
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="the_input_id1"/> 
<input type="text" id="the_input_id2"/> 
<input type="text" id="the_input_id3"/> 
<input type="text" id="total">
```